# how to convert object to string in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Below i have pasted my piece of javascript  code here

1)

```
  function showCustomerName(dropdown) {
  var selectedCustomer = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
  var currentCustomer = document.getElementById('currentCustomer');
  alert(selectedCustomer); 

  var context = document.forms[0].context.value;
  document.forms[0].mode.value = "UPDATE";
  document.forms[0].custName.value = selectedCustomer ;
  document.forms[0].action=context+"/updateReportDetail.do";
  document.forms[0].method="POST";
  document.forms[0].submit();
}
```

2)

```
 function showCustomerID(dropdown) {
  var currentCustomer = document.getElementById('currentCustomer');
  var selectedCustomerID = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
  alert(selectedCustomerID);   

  var context = document.forms[0].context.value;
  document.forms[0].mode.value = "UPDATE";
  document.forms[0].custName.value = currentCustomer;
  document.forms[0].custID.value = selectedCustomerID ;
  document.forms[0].action=context+"/updateReportDetail.do";
  document.forms[0].method="POST";
  document.forms[0].submit();
}


<select id="currentCustomer" onchange="showCustomerName(this)">
 <c:forEach var="Customer" items="${listCustomer}" >
   <option value="<c:out value="${Customer}" />"><c:out value="${Customer}" />
   </option>
  </c:forEach>
 </select>

<select id="currentCustomerID" onchange="showCustomerID(this)">
 <c:forEach var="CustomerID" items="${listCustomerID}" >
   <option value="<c:out value="${CustomerID}" />"><c:out value="${CustomerID}" />
   </option>
  </c:forEach>
 </select>
```

the above code is working fine.
The thing is  i need to retrieving  value from "showCustomerName()" to "showCustomerID()" script .

In "showCustomerID()" script method i am retrieving "showCustomerName()" methods value as object

```
var currentCustomer = document.getElementById('currentCustomer');
```

how to retrieve it as a value? i dont want to retrieve as object

please help me guys.

Comment: Can't you call currentCustomer.toString()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just need to grab the value

```
var currentCustomer = document.getElementById('currentCustomer').value;
alert(currentCustomer);
```

Though you should make sure it exsts

```
var currentCustomerElement = document.getElementById('currentCustomer');
var currentCustomer = (currentCustomerElement) ? currentCustomerElement.value : "not found";
```

Or am I misunderstanding what you are trying to retrieve?

Answer (score 2):

Did you tried this :

```
var currentCustomer = document.getElementById('currentCustomer').value;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var currentCustomer = document.getElementById('currentCustomer').value;
```

Getting an element is an object. You can then target the object to get its value.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var currentCustomer = document.getElementById('currentCustomer').value;
```

Answer (score 1):

`getElementById` is going to return the element as an object.  There's no way around that.

What you need to do is get the value outof that:

```
var currentCustomerEle = document.getElementById('currentCustomer'); 
var currentCustomer = currentCustomerEle.value;
```

or you could do it in one line:

```
var currentCustomer = document.getElementById('currentCustomer').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Does:

```
var currentCustomer = document.getElementById('currentCustomer').value;
```

return a `string` for a *form type* `{input type="text" id="currentCustomer"}`

Comment: Your answer doesn't really add anything to the many anwers already given to the question.